# Simple radial gradient background in Metro-Style App

Tags: c#, xaml, directx, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

What would be a simple way of drawing a radial gradient background (also being able to change it's color) in a XAML/C# Metro-Style App ? 
Is using DirectX an option ? I tried looking at some SharpDX samples for Windows 8 Consumer Preview but failed to compile them. Haven't found any other samples of using DX in C# on Windows 8.
Any ideas ?

Comment: XAML can do gradients. And the Metro guidelines say you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Radial gradients are not there in the XAML framework. There is nothing in the Metro guidelines about not using gradients as far as I know. Can you point me to where you have seen that statement? Also - Windows 8 Metro-Style Apps do not have to follow Metro design language, so it should not matter - it is just an unfortunate name choice for the sandboxed WinRT apps.

Comment: Many of the tiles on the Start menu clearly have gradient backgrounds. Gradients can be used to great effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadialGradientBrush has not been added to the XAML stack yet. You can use WriteableBitmapEx to draw the gradient to a WriteableBitmap yourself and then use an Image or ImageBrush to display it - although that could be prohibitively slow if you have many elements that you want to use differently shaped gradients on.

You could just use a regular image created in Photoshop or Paint.NET.

Using DirectX might be too complicated and not really necessary, but you can mix DirectX with XAML. If you really want to go there - you would probably need to use SurfaceImageSource. There is a basic introduction on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) or check a SharpDX sample [here](http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/directx-in-your-winrt-xamlc-apps-sharpdx/). You would probably also want to use Direct2D to render to that surface, so there are quite a few technologies you would need to mix.

Comment: As far as I've read WriteableBitmapEx isn't supported in metro...
I found that same SharpDX sample myself, but haven't managed to wrap my head around it yet, even though I've worked a bit with OpenGL in the past :(

Comment: Sorry, forgot to link - I ported WriteableBitmapEx to WinRT - you can grab it here: http://bit.ly/WriteableBitmapExWinRT

Comment: Any idea how I could speed it up a bit ? I'm setting every individual pixel in a quadrant and then using symmetry, but for a gradient that has it's start/end point outside of the screen I end up having to set every pixel anyway. I'm using the gradient only on the background of the main 'window' ,but it has to be changed once the user changes the theme.

Answer (score 2):

I used SharpDx to overcome this hurdle and create me a RadialGradient filled background

http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/radial-gradients-mini-path-geometry-sprites-infinite-scrolling-inertial-canvas/

Comment: Hello battery consumption.

Answer (score -8):

Radial gradient brushes have been around for quite a while - I think the first time I used one was in 2008. Anyway, the markup in xaml is pretty simple:

```
<Rectangle Width="200" Height="100">
      <Rectangle.Fill>
        <RadialGradientBrush 
          GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
          Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
          <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
            <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1" />
          </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
      </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

Full details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752281(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: RadialGradientBrush isn't available on Metro

Comment: Maybe I'm reading too far into the original post, but he said metro-style which makes me think vanilla wpf or silverlight.

Comment: Since the OP tagged the message with WinRT, I think it's safe to assume that this solution won't work at this point in Windows 8 "The artist formerly known as Metro" Apps.

Comment: RadialGradientBrush is not available in the RTM version either