# RadialGradientBrush in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Please tell me how can I create a RadialGradientBrush in Windows Phone 8.1 app?

I've tried to find it here but there is no such brush

```
 Windows.UI.Xaml.Media
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: RadialGradient is not included in WinRT:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362063/simple-radial-gradient-background-in-metro-style-app

Comment: @Dani oh, didn't find that question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing the new Microsoft's Win2D library from NuGet or their [Win2D GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D), you can use the `Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasRadialGradientBrush`.
For further reference:

[Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasRadialGradientBrush](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasRadialGradientBrush.htm)