# Windows phone 8 color animation

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to change the background color of screen form red to green but i also want the color to change with an outward effect.
The code that i am using changes the color of whole screen but how to show the outward effect?
by outward i mean that the color changes form center to the end of the page like a flow.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" Background="Red"
  Loaded="Start_Animation">
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="colorStoryboard">

      <!-- Animate the background color of the canvas from red to green
        over 4 seconds. -->
      <ColorAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="myStackPanel" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
        From="Red" To="Green" Duration="0:0:4" />

    </Storyboard>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after a `RadialGradientBrush` (that you can overlay and then animate).

That was asked already: [RadialGradientBrush in Windows Phone 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943177/radialgradientbrush-in-windows-phone-8-1)